# Cannot set dynamic styling in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I need to dynamically set the width of certain elements based on record data. 
I've tried the following code but it just doesn't work. 
Any ideas?

JS file:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import getTicketingInfo from '@salesforce/apex/TicketmaticWidgetController.getTicketingInfo'; 

export default class TicketWidget extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId; 
    @wire(getTicketingInfo, {recordId: '$recordId'}) ticketingInfo; 

   renderedCallback() {
       let calculation = (this.ticketingInfo.data.SoldPaid__c / this.ticketingInfo.data.TotalTickets__c) * 1000;
       let calculationString = calculation.toString(); 
       let widthString = calculationString.concat('px;'); 
       let sold = this.template.querySelector('.sold'); 
       sold.style.width = widthString; 
   }
}
```

HTML file:

```
<ul class="bar">
          <li class="bar-item sold">{ticketingInfo.data.SoldPaid__c}</li>
          <li class="bar-item complimentary">{ticketingInfo.data.Complimentary__c}</li>
          <li class="bar-item reserved">{ticketingInfo.data.Reserved__c}</li>
          <li class="bar-item locked">{ticketingInfo.data.Locked__c}</li>
          <li class="bar-item free">{ticketingInfo.data.Free__c}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I do is create getter for each particular style required by each element. I'm not entirely sure why your direct style assignment is failing, but getters do work.

```
<ul class="bar">
  <li class="bar-item sold" style={soldStyle}>{ticketingInfo.data.SoldPaid__c}</li>
  <li class="bar-item complimentary" style={complimentaryStyle}>{ticketingInfo.data.Complimentary__c}</li>
</ul>


get soldStyle(){() {
  let calculation = (this.ticketingInfo.data.SoldPaid__c / this.ticketingInfo.data.TotalTickets__c) * 1000;
  let calculationString = calculation.toString(); 
  return 'width:' +  calculationString.concat('px;'); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Just to note that I actually tried this solution before, but I got an error in the html file. Turned out I had to deploy the component on the main directory level and not just the html file. The errors persist though, I use VScode as a reference.

Comment: That's weird - is it an html parser error?

Comment: And yeah, you have to deploy the whole package I think.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't recognize the syntax. Errors:
} expected & 
at-rule or selector expected